# How to undo a camera binding to a marker?

Tags: animation, camera

I am doing an animation, and I require to take several shots from multiple angles, and I'm doing it by binding cameras to markers in the timeline. I accidentally binded a camera to an incorrect marker and I don't want to delete the camera. How could I undo this?

Comment: You can bind another camera to this marker, its data will be automatically rewritten

Answer (score 2):

Just select the marker from the **timeline** and press <kbd>X</kbd> to delete the marker.
Note: Your cursor must be on the timeline to delete from timeline.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem. Here's a fix I just did. I created a new camera, bound it to that marker in order to release the existing bounded camera, and then I deleted that new camera aftetwards.